# Как сделать запрет или отмену прокрутки?

Tags: jquery

```js
$('.section.active').fadeIn(1000);
//Firefox
$('body,html').bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){


  var currentSlideIndex = $('.section.active').index(),
      nextSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex + 1;
      nextSlide = $('.section').eq(nextSlideIndex),
      prevSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex - 1;
      prevSlide = $('.section').eq(prevSlideIndex);


  if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
    //scroll down
    if(nextSlideIndex == ($('.section:last').index() + 1)) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      $('.section').removeClass('active').fadeOut();
      $(nextSlide).addClass('active').fadeIn(1000);
    }
  }else {
    //scroll up
    if(prevSlideIndex == ($('.section:first-child').index() - 1)) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      $('.section').removeClass('active').fadeOut();
      $(prevSlide).addClass('active').fadeIn(1000);
    }
  }

  //prevent page fom scrolling
  return false;
});

//IE, Opera, Safari
$('body,html').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
  var currentSlideIndex = $('.section.active').index(),
    nextSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex + 1;
    nextSlide = $('.section').eq(nextSlideIndex),
    prevSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex - 1;
    prevSlide = $('.section').eq(prevSlideIndex);

  if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
    //scroll down
    if(nextSlideIndex == ($('.section:last').index() + 1)) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      $('.section').removeClass('active').fadeOut();
      $(nextSlide).addClass('active').fadeIn(1000);
    }

  }else {
    //scroll up

    if(prevSlideIndex == ($('.section:first-child').index() - 1)) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      $('.section').removeClass('active').fadeOut();
      $(prevSlide).addClass('active').fadeIn(1000);
    }


  }

  //prevent page fom scrolling
  return false;
});
```

```css
body {
 overflow: hidden;
 }
 .section {
 display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section active">text1</div>
    <div class="section ">text2</div>
      <div class="section ">text3</div>
        <div class="section ">text4</div>  <div class="section active"></div>
          <div class="section ">text5</div>
```

Как сделать запрет или отмену прокрутки? То есть если пользователь много раз крутил вниз что бы сработало только 1 раз ? или же если покуртил вниз и потом вверх анимация пошла обратно и открылся предыдущий слайд??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как сделать запрет или отмену прокрутки? То есть если пользователь
>   много раз крутил вниз что бы сработало только 1 раз ?

Вы можете использовать паттерн debounce, реализованный, например, в [этом плагине](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce).

```
// Обратите внимание, что вы можете указать два события в bind,
// не обязательно дублировать обработчики, если код идентичен.
// Для определения браузера лучше использовать логику внутри функции
$('body,html').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', $.debounce(250, function(e) {
...
}));
```

Код обработчика будет вызываться не чаще, чем раз в 250 миллисекунд.

Comment: когда так написал bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',  
то в хроме перестало работать. Если по отдельности написать то все нормально

Comment: Видимо, проблема в самой функции (там немного различается код), потому что код `$('body, html').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScrol', function() { console.log('scroll') });` корректно отрабатывает в хроме